R filter out rows based on value in different row
Here's an example df:
df <- data.frame(
  id= c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
  admit_dt = c("2022-01-01", "" ,"2022-05-05","", "", "2022-09-03", "", ""),
  discharge_dt = c("2022-01-04","", "2022-05-06","","", "2022-09-04", "", ""),
  first_dt = c("2022-01-01", "2022-01-02", "2022-05-05", "2022-06-09", "2022-01-03", "2022-09-03", "2022-10-10", "2022-09-04")
)

I need to filter out rows where for each unique id, there's a date value in first_dt that is  between (inclusive) the admit_dt and discharge_dt in any other row for the same id.  So I want to keep row 1 in the above df, but get rid of row 2, since the value in first_dt is between the value in admit_dt and discharge_dt in row 1.  I'd want to end up with this df:



id
admit_dt
discharge_dt
first_dt




1
2022-01-01
2022-01-04
2022-01-01


1
2022-05-05
2022-05-06
2022-05-05


1


2022-06-09


2


2022-01-03


2
2022-09-03
2022-09-04
2022-09-03


2


2022-10-10



Thank you for any suggestions!

How do you deal with a value which is in between in one row but not in between in another row?

As long as the value in first_dt is between admit_dt and discharge_dt in any row but the row it is in (for the same id), that row should be removed.

library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(
  id= c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
  admit_dt = c("2022-01-01", "" ,"2022-05-05","", "", "2022-09-03", "", ""),
  discharge_dt = c("2022-01-04","", "2022-05-06","","", "2022-09-04", "", ""),
  first_dt = c("2022-01-01", "2022-01-02", "2022-05-05", "2022-06-09", "2022-01-03", "2022-09-03", "2022-10-10", "2022-09-04")
)

goal_df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~id,    ~admit_dt, ~discharge_dt,    ~first_dt,
  1, "2022-01-01",  "2022-01-04", "2022-01-01",
  1, "2022-05-05",  "2022-05-06", "2022-05-05",
  1,           "",             "", "2022-06-09",
  2,            "",             "", "2022-01-03",
  2, "2022-09-03",  "2022-09-04", "2022-09-03",
  2,            "",             "", "2022-10-10"
)




# filter out rows where for each unique id, 
# there's a date value in first_dt 
# that  in any other row for the same id is between (inclusive) the admit_dt and discharge_dt 

# add rownumbers
dfr <- df |> mutate(rn=row_number())

# get a set of data which is all the original rows, joined to their same id, but different rownumber counterparts

df2 <- left_join(dfr,
  dfr |> rename_all(\(x)paste0(x, "_2")),
  by = join_by(id == id_2, between(
    first_dt,
    admit_dt_2,
    discharge_dt_2
  ))
) |> mutate(dropme= rn_2 != rn)

df3 <- df2 |> filter(!dropme | is.na(dropme))

cleanedup <- select(df3,
                    id,admit_dt,
                    discharge_dt,
                    first_dt)

identical(cleanedup,goal_df)
 


As far as I can tell with my more complex df, this did the trick - thank you!

library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(
  id= c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
  admit_dt = c("2022-01-01", "" ,"2022-05-05","", "", "2022-09-03", "", ""),
  discharge_dt = c("2022-01-04","", "2022-05-06","","", "2022-09-04", "", ""),
  first_dt = c("2022-01-01", "2022-01-02", "2022-05-05", "2022-06-09", "2022-01-03", "2022-09-03", "2022-10-10", "2022-09-04")
) |> 
  mutate_if(is.character, as.Date) |> #convert the string dates to dates
  mutate(Row_Number = row_number()) # add row_number to each row 




df_for_comparison <- df |> 
  #keep only rows where admit_dt and first_dt are not NA.
  filter(!is.na(admit_dt) & !is.na(first_dt)) |> 
  #keep only the fields we need for comparison: id,Row_Number (rename to Row_Number_Comparison), 
    #admit_dt, and discharge_dt
  select(id, Row_Number_Comparison = Row_Number, admit_dt, discharge_dt)


rows_to_exclude <- df |> 
  #select just the fields we need for comparison from df: id, Row_Number, and first_dt
  select(id, Row_Number, first_dt) |> 
  #join the comparison data.frame based on the id column
  left_join(df_for_comparison, by = join_by(id)) |> 
  #exclude rows that were joined to the same data in df (where Record_Number == Row_Number_Comparison)
  filter(Row_Number != Row_Number_Comparison) |> 
  #set exclude to true when first_dt is between admit_dt and discharge_dt
  mutate(exclude = between(first_dt, admit_dt, discharge_dt)) |> 
  #keep only rows in the data where exclude == TRUE
  filter(exclude) |> 
  #keep only unique Row_Numbers where exclude == TRUE
  distinct(Row_Number) |>
  #Get a vector with the row numbers that we want to exclude
  pull(Row_Number) 

## or an alternative way to do this step:
rows_to_exclude <- df |> 
  #select just the fields we need for comparison from df: id, Row_Number, and first_dt
  select(id, Row_Number, first_dt) |> 
  #join the comparison data.frame based on the id column and keep only records where first_dt in 
  # df is between admit_dt and discharge_dt in df_for_comparison
  left_join(df_for_comparison, by = join_by(id, between(first_dt, admit_dt, discharge_dt))) |> 
  #exclude rows that were joined to the same data in df (where Record_Number == Row_Number_Comparison)
  filter(Row_Number != Row_Number_Comparison) |> 
#keep distinct Row_Numbers to exclude
  distinct(Row_Number) |> 
#get a vector with the row numbers to exclude
  pull(Row_Number)  

# remove the excluded rows from the data.frame
df |> filter(!Row_Number %in% rows_to_exclude) |> 
  #If you no longer want the row number field remove it
  select(-Row_Number)

#Alternative way to do the last step:
df[-rows_to_exclude,] |> 
  select(-Row_Number)


  id   admit_dt discharge_dt   first_dt
1  1 2022-01-01   2022-01-04 2022-01-01
2  1 2022-05-05   2022-05-06 2022-05-05
3  1       <NA>         <NA> 2022-06-09
4  2       <NA>         <NA> 2022-01-03
5  2 2022-09-03   2022-09-04 2022-09-03
6  2       <NA>         <NA> 2022-10-10


Thank you!  This works too; it differs from the previous answer in that if an admit_dt value is the same as another row's discharge_dt, this solution removes the row whereas the previous solution does not.  I didn't realize I had data like this in the dataset so this was really helpful.
